# PHP require vs autoload

Tags: php, mysql, require

I'm new of PHP. I have 8 php file for function and class.(5 file function and 3 file class) now I need to required all 8 files to my php header file and include this for all page like this:

```
require('/includes/function1.php');
require('/includes/function2.php');
require('/includes/function3.php');
require('/includes/function4.php');
require('/includes/function5.php');
require('/includes/class1.php');
require('/includes/class2.php');
require('/includes/class3.php');
```

now, my question is: for my files `require` is best choose? or I try with `autoload` function? which way is better / fast / boost and increase my code and server?!

Comment: Autoload only works with classes, so your choice is either to continue to use require/include, or to wrap your functions in static methods. Either way speed differences are negligible - the benefit to autoload is development ease, not running speed

Answer (score 2):

You may define an __autoload() function which is automatically called in case you are trying to use a class/interface which hasn't been defined yet. By calling this function the scripting engine is given a last chance to load the class before PHP fails with an error.

So This is better way to include your files as above. Please visit [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for more description.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice is a matter of opinion, but I would go with an autoloader. You already have a lot of includes and as your script grows you'll likely add more, managing code like this can be difficult.

Using an autoloader would be marginally slower, but I mean fractionally, a tiny amount. This is simply because the code in the autoload function has to run each time a file is needed. The difference in time would be negligible.

Autoloaders only work for classes, not functions. My advice for functions would be to wrap them in classes, perhaps making the methods static.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include your classes for all pages, it is better to create an `init.php` file with the includes, and include this `init.php` on all pages (and use `require_once()` instead of `require()`). Use initializers, when your includes are fixed and commonly used.

It is a good choice to use the [spl_autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) method. This is an `__autoload()` implementation with support of multiple autoloader functions. Use autoloading in each case, when you do not know ahead of time where you'll need it.

Comment: He mentioned speed. require_once() has a performance penalty over require().  Though it's a slight penalty, this isn't the most performant option.